# Use Powershell to install windows Patches

Tags: powershell

I already tried alot of tips on Stackoverflow, but nothing seems to work.
If I run this Code a [Window Pops up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAxJU.png).

The PowerShell Version is 2.0

My Code:

```
$PATH = "S:\User\Person\UPDATES\Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB3134760)\AMD64-all-windows6.1-kb3134760-x64_d720851ef4b5a37c1c8bdd2e5bf4c77dcc625e8c.msu"

$SB = {Start-Process -FilePath 'c:\windows\system32\wusa.exe' -ArgumentList ('S:\User\Voss\UPDATES\Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB3134760)\AMD64-all-windows6.1-kb3134760-x64_d720851ef4b5a37c1c8bdd2e5bf4c77dcc625e8c.msu','/quiet', '/promtrestart', "/log:S:\User\Voss\UPDATES\Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB3134760)\Update.log") -Wait}

$computer = echo (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -Property Name).Name

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $SB
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the actual answer, but you misspelled `/promptrestart`

Comment: If I recall correctly, there is a limitation with running wusa.exe over a remote session. I believe you have to do a workaround like have the remote job create a scheduled task etc. (besides the typo, which is why you have the dialog box that pops up from incorrect arguments)

Answer (score 0):

First off, E.D. (hehe) is correct about your spelling error.  A simple syntax error can break even the most otherwise elegant/complex scripts.

You're going to a lot of additional trouble to install patches from what I'm assuming is a (remote) mapped drive.  If you're trying to do this on other machines, you'll want to use something like psexec or a scheduled task to kick off the install under the machines' credentials (NT Authority\System).  If you're doing this on your machine and FOR your machine.

Picking your code apart:

```
$PATH = "S:\User\Person\UPDATES\Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB3134760)\AMD64-all-windows6.1-kb3134760-x64_d720851ef4b5a37c1c8bdd2e5bf4c77dcc625e8c.msu"

$SB = {Start-Process -FilePath 'c:\windows\system32\wusa.exe' -ArgumentList ('S:\User\Voss\UPDATES\Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB3134760)\AMD64-all-windows6.1-kb3134760-x64_d720851ef4b5a37c1c8bdd2e5bf4c77dcc625e8c.msu','/quiet', '/promtrestart', "/log:S:\User\Voss\UPDATES\Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB3134760)\Update.log") -Wait}

$computer = echo (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -Property Name).Name

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $SB
```

1) I don't really understand what you're doing with the $PATH variable as it isn't referenced anywhere else.

2) $SB doesn't 'REALLY' need to be delimited that way, but should work.  Normally, I would just make it a single string and, when referencing other variables, utilize this syntax to get them to be evaluated first - $($PATH)

3) for $computer, you're kind of right.  Lose the echo and you should be fine since you're just getting the name of the local machine ( $Env:ComputerName would work just as well and be more economical even if you're running the code on another machine, IMHO )

Addressing the use case where you might be running this code on another machine:

You seem to be assuming that you are logged on and your drive mapping is applicable.  If you're accessing a network share, you'd want to make sure the remote machine has read permissions to the share so it could get to the file(s) in question and you'll also want to use the UNC path for simplicity's sake.  This is a situation where psexec \ -S WUSA \UNC PATH\To\Update\File.msu would be best utilized.

Bottom line, if you'd communicate what your intent is a bit better, I might be better able to assist.